# XLWings Throwing Error on quit after a copy

Tags: python, xlwings, application-error

When running xlwings 0.26.1 (latest for Anaconda 3.83) or 0.10.0 (using for compatibility reasons) with the latest version of `Office 365 Excel`, I get an error after moving a sheet when running `app.quit()`:

```
import xlwings as xw
import pythoncom

pythoncom.CoInitialize()
app = xw.apps.add()
app.display_alerts = False
app.screen_updating = False

wbSource = app.books.open('pathSourceTemp')
wsSource = wbSource.sheets['sourceSheet']
wbDestination = app.books.open('pathDestinationTemp')
wsDestination = None

#Grabs first sheet in destination
wsDestination = wbDestination.sheets[0]


#Copy sheet "before" destination sheet (which should be 1 sheet after the destination sheet)
wsSource.api.Copy(Before=wsDestination.api)
wbDestination.save()

#Close workbooks and app
wbDestination.close()
wbSource.close()
app.screen_updating = True
app.quit()
```

The final line causes Excel to throw an error that I have to click out of for the process to continue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found which works with both `xlwings 0.10.0` and `0.26.1` is to simply brute force with the `app.kill()` method:

```
#Close workbooks and app
wbDestination.close()
wbSource.close()
app.screen_updating = True
#app.quit() <- throws error
app.kill() <- no error
```

Not sure what unintended side effects this might have, but apparently the `.kill()` command [was introduced](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html) in version `0.9.0`. As long as you close the workbooks first, I dont see how it can cause any problems with data loss or corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 0.24.3, the idiomatic way is using [`with xw.App() as app`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/whatsnew.html#v0-24-3-jul-15-2021).
The advantage of this is that there won't be any hidden excel processes left over in the background, if you use a hidden instance (`visible=False`) and your code fails.

```
import xlwings as xw

# You could also omit .screen_updating (and .display_alerts)
# and use xw.App(visible=False) instead, if appropriate.
with xw.App() as app:
    app.display_alerts = False
    app.screen_updating = False

    wbSource = xw.Book()
    wbDestination = xw.Book()

    # Do your stuff here.

    app.screen_updating = True
    # Save as needed, for example: wbDestination.save()
    wbSource.close()
    wbDestination.close()
```